# Background image is taking very long time to open

Tags: css, image, optimization, background, css-transitions

the background image of my website yuconexports.com is taking very long time to load. 
I don't know how to solve it. 
I have tried all possible measures mentioned; it is compressed, it is not even being repeated,  the image is 372*571 and is just of 167 kb.

Kindly help me since the background image is taking very long time to open.

Comment: It loaded just fine, if you're on dial up nothing you can do tbh.

Comment: you can image slicing and upload really it takes no more time.

Comment: that's load fine,but you can smaller img for load faster

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the javascript tags to the bottom of the page. Javascript loads and is parsed synchronously, so the browser can't download images while downloading and parsing Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can crop your background image to 1px size and repeat it.

```
background-repeat:repeat;
```

and on thing is that your banner images also take long time.
incresing use of color instead of images where you want.